# Matching multiple words, selecting the ones that match with multiple

Tags: sql

I have two tables first table looks like

| key | value |
| --- | --- |
| key1 | word1 |
| key1 | word2 |
| key1 | word3 |
| key2 | word4 |
| key2 | word5 |
| key3 | word6 |

the second table looks like

| otherkey | value |
| --- | --- |
| otherkey1 | word1 |
| otherkey2 | word1 |
| otherkey2 | word2 |
| otherkey2 | word3 |
| otherkey2 | word9 |
| otherkey3 | word4 |
| otherkey3 | word5 |
| otherkey4 | word4 |
| otherkey5 | word1 |
| otherkey6 | word6 |

And what i want is

| key | otherkey | combined | count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| key1 | otherykey1 | word1 | 1 |
| key1 | otherykey2 | word1 word2 word3 | 3 |
| key2 | otherykey3 | word 4 word5 | 2 |
| key3 | otherykey6 | word6 | 1 |

What I've come up with work but is dreadfully slow and I'm wondering if there isn't a better way to do this, table1 is around 25k rows, table 2 contains 25m rows

1 Value in table 1 can be 1000 times in table 2

And i'm only interested in the keys from table 1 that have multiple matches in table2

```
SELECT
    *
FROM (
    SELECT
        key
       ,otherkey
       ,COUNT(otherkey)    count                                                 
       ,STRING_AGG(s.[value], ' ')   combined                                      
       ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY keu ORDER BY COUNT(otherkey) DESC) rn
    FROM table1 n
    LEFT JOIN table2 s
        ON s.value = n.value
        AND key IS NOT NULL
    GROUP BY key
            ,otherkey
) X
WHERE rn < 10;
```

Answer (score 0):

This should perform better [Working example is here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=019044ebd3c0ccf01deaacaee8b04c3a)

```
select t1_key,t2_key,combined,count(t1_key) from (

select aggr.t1_key ,aggr.t2_key ,(select STRING_AGG(value,' ') from table2 where t2_key = aggr.t2_key ) as combined from 
(select t1_key,t2_key from table1 left join table2 on table1.value = table2.value ) as aggr ) as whole 

group by t1_key,t2_key,combined
```